# Monitoring traffic on Netgear GS752TPS

Tags: netgear-prosafe

We run 5 x GS752TPS as a single stack. We run both our data and voice on the same network.

As far as I know, no advanced setup has been done on the switches.

I'd like to remove the infrastructure as a possible cause for the network running slow. How can I measure the load the switches are put under?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have different models (GS752TXS and GS752TP, last one non-stackable) but I think this is a comparable setup since we also use it with a voice network (but in different VLAN).

I activated SNMP on the devices with a custom secret and installed a Ubuntu VM with [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) on it and I really like it. It really takes some time to get a well functioning setup with all measurements but today I´ve integrated a lot of our central devices (switches, firewall, vmware-servers, ...) and it *really* is a very good tool to answere a lot of questions... about stability, performance, traffic and so on.

With our Netgear switches (and on the firewall) we´re counting traffic for all LAGs and some specific ports. That might be exactly what you want to have.

I would give it a try.... but to be honest: In most cases it´s NOT the switch ;-)

Is your Voice-network a problem or transfer speeds of the "normal" network? I hope you´re using QOS properly...!? With activated 802.1p we really have no problems here.

Comment: For a switch, Cacti is really easy to configure. Name the ports in the switch config and they will pull through when you set up the graphs.  I have done this for a set of GS728T's and it worked great.  But at this point I hope that @jidl has either fixed his issue or moved on to a different company ;)

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look. We are looking into separating the voice onto a different VLAN (although I've read that his doesn't improve performance). Problems are mainly around an SOP on local SQL Server (nowhere near capacity) running slowly and our hosted exchange disconnecting from Outlook clients randomly.

Comment: @JeffMeden Unfortunately not... :) Lack of funding for replacing equipment and tied into a contract on the hosted means I (and my users) have to endure the problem!

Comment: Just saw the date of the question ;-) Had a similar issue with dropping connections too because I had multiple connections between each switch-connections everywhere but forgot to specify a LAG at one point. The one switch had the LAG specified - the other had not.... that was cause of a regular loss of connection.

Comment: Separating Voice LAN to antother VLAN does not improve performance... For us it´s just a separation for security reasons and and an indicator that the QOS-rules apply. I don´t want anybody to access the configuration of our phones or to make a SIP-access to our PBX.

Comment: The switches are in a management stack connected by fiber - not sure if LAG applies on the SFP ports.

Comment: Is it just the VOIP audio that indicates a slowdown because of quality degradation?

Comment: We've a Mitel HX5000 in house - there have been some complaints of calls taking time (20 - 30 seconds) to connect but no quality degradation during calls. the main driver for looking at it is the SOP performance on clients and hosted exchange disconnects.

Comment: The stack does not need difinition of LAGs - if it´s recognized correctly. The switches should be connected in a double-ring. We have a Mitel-PBX too - but no complaints about anything here. Did you activate LLDP? I would give the build-in Auto.-VLAN option a try.... You just have to add the Mitel OUI to the list, activate it and reboot your phones - and update the connection of your PBX to the new VLAN. Activate QOS 802.1p as said and all should work flawlessly.